# Finding the adjoint of a matrix with functional component.

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

Suppose I have the following matrix.
$$A ``=" \left[\begin{matrix} a & b\\ L & d\end{matrix}\right]$$ where $L$ is a functional on $l^2$. I want to find $A^*$, but it seems like the usual thing,
$A^* = (\overline{A})^T$, fails because of $L$. I want to check if $A$ is self-adjoint, so suppose $L$ is self-adjoint and $a, b, d$ are real, how do I compute the adjoint of $A$?

Thank you.

Comment: Any chance you could change your notation?  Right now you're using $T$ for a functional _and_ for the transpose of a matrix.

Comment: Yes, I just did. Thank you.

Comment: The notion of adjoint applies to an operator, not to a matrix. So, in what sense do you see your $A$ as an operator? That would determine what the adjoint is.